# Warning: Encountered two children with the same key when implementing a Search Filter in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, search, react-hooks

I'm new to React, and I have been trying to implement a search filter on the data that I have. However, on entering the query in the search bar, I'm getting this error in the console.

```
index.js:1 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `.$-M9EdZMRAOiy_QUS1yKA`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.
in ul (created by ForwardRef(GridList))
in ForwardRef(GridList) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(GridList)))
in WithStyles(ForwardRef(GridList)) (at space-card-grid.tsx:32)
in SpaceCardGrid (at search.tsx:59)
in div (at search.tsx:58)
in div (created by Col)
in Col (at search.tsx:57)
in div (created by Row)
in Row (at search.tsx:56)
in div (created by Container)
in Container (at search.tsx:55)
in div (at search.tsx:45)
in SearchPage (created by Context.Consumer)
in Route (at routes.tsx:9)
in Switch (at routes.tsx:8)
in Routes (at src/index.tsx:15)
in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
in BrowserRouter (at src/index.tsx:14)
in div (at src/index.tsx:13)
in FirebaseProvider (at src/index.tsx:11)
```

I'm getting repeated errors even as I'm trying to input, again and again, causing the application to crash. Here is the code, I have written for the Search Filter.

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Col, Container, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import SpaceCardGrid from '../space-card-grid/space-card-grid';
import { MDBCol } from 'mdbreact';
import { firebaseDb } from '../../utils/firebase/index';

type SpaceType = {
  id: string;
  description: string;
  title: string;
  imageId: number;
  likes: number;
  eventDate: string;
  startTime: string;
  endTime: string;
};

const allSpaces: SpaceType[] = [];
const SearchPage = () => {
  const [spaces, setSpaces] = useState<SpaceType[]>([]);

  firebaseDb.ref(`studios`).once('value', (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((space) => {
      allSpaces.push({ ...space.val(), id: space.key });
    });
    setSpaces(allSpaces.reverse());
  });

  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState({ query: '' });
  const spaceCardGridRef = useRef(null);

  const searchQueryHandler = (event) => {
    setSearchQuery({ query: event.target.value });
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  let filteredspaces = spaces;

  if (searchQuery.query !== '')
    filteredspaces = spaces.filter((space) => {
      return space.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchQuery.query.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });

  return (
    <div>
      <br></br>
      <MDBCol md="6">
        <input
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Search spaces of interest"
          onChange={searchQueryHandler}
          value={searchQuery.query}
        />
      </MDBCol>
      <Container fluid className="bottom-container">
        <Row style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'flex-start' }}>
          <Col>
            <div className="grid-root">
              <SpaceCardGrid spaces={filteredspaces} spaceCardGridRef={spaceCardGridRef} />
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchPage;
```

I'm reading data from firebase and then using it (I doubt the issue is here). All the data is being read and displayed on the screen properly. The issue only shows up when I start searching.

I attach a screenshot of my browser for more clarity.

[image: Screenshot of my browser]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `GridList` component, you can make the keys of the mapped array more unique by appending the index of the element to the end for example:

```js
items.map((item, index) => <GridItem key={`item.id-index`}>{/* ...your logic... */});
```

Comment: Should I show you the code where I have rendered the GirdList?

Comment: yes, please. It would be best if you could create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io)

Comment: I'm sorry for this late comment, but I was able to manage to resolve that error. It was because I was calling all the objects from the database again and again with each query in the search bar, and that is what resulted in multiple children having same keys.